# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol while using CRect

Tags: c++, winapi, window

```
    I am trying to use the CRect to create a rectangle.
    While compiling the below mentioned Code

    #include <windows.h>
    #include <atltypes.h>



    CRect rectRgn;
    int main()
    {
      ///////////// some line of code
    }
```

I am getting linker error in that. 
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CRect::CRect(void)" (??0CRect@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'rectRgn''(void)" (??__ErectRgn@@YAXXZ)

Here is the link from MSDN on CRect.
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y3502k0.aspx
I have included the atltypes.h Header.
Please provide your input.
        Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jonathan, that question is not having my answer, in my case i have included the header file atltypes.h which containing the CRect api. Might be there is some lib missing in my case. i am not able to figure it out, bcoz at the time of creating the object only i am getting this linker error.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on. `CRect` definition is contained within `<atltypes.h>` so this should work as long as it compiles. If you can't solve this then just use `RECT`.

Comment: Thanks Barmak, yes Rect is working fine. But still i don't know the Reason for CRect not working.

Comment: Well, have you linked the ATL library to your project? Despite its name, ATL is *not* an entirely-inline, header-only template library (especially as CRect is, IIRC, not a template class).